# Two Server which is behind load balancer must not be called directly from Public

Tags: webserver, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I have facing with an issue in my lab. My lab infra is on Digital Ocean. I have two servers (Droplets) and one Load Balancer. The two servers are actually webservers. I can call the website from Load Balancer. But, I only want to call from the load balancer not directly from the webservers.
How can I manage to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Drop the public IP of the servers
2. Block the requests via a firewall if they are not coming from your load balancers
3. Don't have the process that is actually serving the requests listen to the public ip of the server